# Union $A \cup B$ and intersection $A\cap B$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Union and intersection of subspaces. I'm trying to find similar examples, but they simply do not exist in quantity.

Consider then the following:

> The vector subspaces: $A = \{ (x, 5x)\mid x\in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $B = \{ (x, 10x)\mid x\in \mathbb{R} \}$
>
> 1. The union $A \cup B$ and interssection $A\cap B$ are vector subspaces?

This is driving me crazy because I cannot see the proper unions and interssection to test vector subspace axioms! I really appreciate a help here in these particular examples.

Comment: Graph them on the $x-y$ coordinate plane.  The graph of $A$ is $y=5x$ and the graph of $B$ is $y=10x$.

Comment: @RobertShore this didn't help me. Please I would kindly ask you to consider to write an answer with algebraic steps.

Comment: "Union an intersection of subspaces."  No it isn't.

Comment: $A\cap B=\{(x,y)|y=5x$ and $y=10x\}$; can you simplify that?

Answer (score 1):

These two lines intersect through the origin but have different slopes. The intersection is a single point, $0$, and that's the trivial vector space. The union is not a vector space. To see this pick any non-zero vector in each subspace and add them together. This vector will not be on either of the lines and so the union is not closed under addition.